# How auto fill the signature on the docusign document when generate document via java code

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying to generate the pdf file and upload to Docusign. Then send it to the user for get confirmation from them
My issue is:
I have sent documents to a lot of users, each document needed two signs from the user and me.
And I will last sign after user was signed thier document.
So I need sign many documents. I don't wants do that. I hope the Docusign will auto sign for me, after each user done.

How can I do it via java code, when I'm generating the document.
Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Please consider to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the stackoverflow `Help Center / asking`. You should at least include in your question what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but it sounds like you mean that you want to use API to sign a document.

This cannot be done. Signing has to be done by a human, showing intent to agree to a contract/agreement. This is an important aspect of signing - that's it done by humans, and not machines. If a machine can sign on my behalf, how do you know that I really knew what I was signing?

If that's the reequipments of your project, you can use UI automation technologies like Selenium or Playwright to automation the UI of the signing.

Now, if you meant something else, that you want to set the signature for a user, not on a specific document, but the way John Doe signs in general, so that when Jane Doe gets a request to sign - The system already knows how Jane Doe signs her contract. This can be done via API, if that's what you meant, but this is different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My requirements is: my director need sign a lot of document after users was signed, and he wants after the users was done, the Docusign autofill his signature or autofill when he open document on Docusign.

Comment: yes, well, you could just have a single signature on each envelope (lots of documents) and have all other signatures baked in side the document. At least one time your director will have to sign, not more than one (for envelope)

Comment: yeah, I updated my post with more details. If you know any idea please help me. thanks

Comment: You are asking something different now, can you open a new question? I can't answer in the comments

Comment: yes, I created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77729882/docusign-i-wants-the-docusign-automatically-sign-for-me-on-my-behalf