# Docusign: I wants the Docusign automatically sign for me on my behalf

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying to generate the document is pdf file via `java code`. Then upload to Docusign and send it to many users for get confirmation from them.
**My issue is**:
I send the document to a lot of users, each document needed two signatures from the user and me.
I will last sign after user was signed their document and completes it.
So I need sign a lot of documents. I don't wants do that. I hope the Docusign automatically sign for me on my behalf of after each user done, then completes that document.

How can I do it via `java code`, while I generating the document.

Answer (score 1):

You take one document, sign it, download the signed PDF that includes your signature.

Then you send it as the document for all these people that need to sign, so it already has your signature in it.

You cannot modify the document AFTER someone signs, and you cannot use API to sign, so the option above is your only option.

Comment: thank you very much Inbar Gazit, I got it, thank for your kindness.

Comment: If I don't want sign it, download the signed PDF then sent for all. I wants add my signature while generating the document via code, then send for all. Can I do that?

Comment: You can probably add it using image generation software, but you cannot use DocuSign to sign automatically

Comment: It will also not be considered a valid signature from a legal point of view if it's done automatically.